# Using theme generated by Holo Style Generator

Tags: android

I managed to get this done a few days back but now I've forgotten what steps I took to make it work.

I've generated a custom widget theme from http://android-holo-colors.com

I've copied it to my res folder. I need to know what to change in the manifest and the styles.xml file to make it work with my app. I've tried a lot of different things but the theme either doesn't change or generates and xml error.

Comment: Can you show your errors and manifest?

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.AppTheme').

Answer (score 0):

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yourapp.app"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.YourTheme"
    ...
</activity>
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Not working. I have this in styles.xml

AppBaseTheme is android:Theme.Light.DarkActionBar (that's was what I chose in the creator)

AppTheme is AppBaseTheme.

Now when designing layout, if I selected ProjectThemes => AppBase theme, its the normal holo theme. But if I select AppTheme, it becomes my color :/

What do I write in manifest now?

Comment: Sorry the AppBaseTheme is android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar